# JSX - Javascript insertion/Weird Parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys so im trying myself  at React.js and i found an example for Event-listeners in JSX.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function makeDoggy(e) {
  // Call this extremely useful function on an <img>.
  // The <img> will become a picture of a doggy.
  e.target.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-puppy.jpeg');
  e.target.setAttribute('alt', 'doggy');
}

const kitty = (
    <img 
        src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-kitty.jpg" 
        alt="kitty" 
        onClick={makeDoggy} 
     />
);

ReactDOM.render(kitty, document.getElementById('app')); */
```

Now. Im trying to understand everything here. I noticed that JSX Event-Lsiteners are written in Camelcase opposed to regular Javascript. And `{}` is used to insert Javascript into JSX but one thing that confuses me (might be bc i am just tired :P) is that `makeDoggy(e)` doesnt get passed anything when its called its just `{makeDoggy}`?! How does it still work, i am a bit confused.Does the `target.setAttribute` have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

> makeDoggy(e) doesnt get passed anything when its called its just {makeDoggy}?!

`onClick={makeDoggy}` does not call makeDoggy. It's just passing a reference of makeDoggy into the onClick handler. When a click event occurs, makeDoggy will get called by react's event-handling code, passing in the event object.

If you changed it to {makeDoggy('something')}, this would immediately call makeDoggy, then take whatever the return value was, and pass that into onClick.

Answer (score 1):

You assign, to the click event handler (which is not the same as the `onclick` HTML attribute), the result of evaluating the expression `makeDoggy` (which is a function).

When the element is clicked, the function will be called and passed an event object.

This isn't specific to React. It is the same in plain DOM:

```js
function eventHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}

document
    .querySelector("button")
    .addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: I just googled event objects. Its very complicated explained. Could you pls simply explain to me what that would be? So is `e` referencing the event object?.... In my mind the `e` just doesnt have a place.

Comment: i think i understand now.The `eventHandler(e)` gets passed the 'click' event?